# Is there any command for PRINT command in Linux just like UNIX

Tags: command

I know the `pr` command and `lpr` on Unix. Is it also the same as that of Linux?

Comment: Linux is just a kernel, it doesn't have commands. There are commands called `pr`, `lpr`, `lp` available for systems running Linux such as Debian, Opensuse, Ubuntu...

Comment: Yes, they probably are close to the same, as is the `man` command. Read `man pr lpr a2ps`.

Comment: Such tools may be optionally installed. In past: Linux was the cheap option for cheap computer (so possible without printer server or printer). Now: printers are seldom. So you may need to install printing command, depending on your distribution.

Comment: There is a whole subsystem called CUPS (Common UNIX Printing System) which manages printer registration, file format conversions, job management and tracking etc, via CLI or GUI. It is smart enough that you hardly know it is there, but `lp` and `lpr` do. `pr` does not print -- it just paginates plain text (adds headers, footers, columns).